# How to make sure mysqli goes through if($result) {} loop?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this php code in my php page. I want to calculate the ticket price based on user's option on quantity. I recently added the **ticketprice** column in my database. Ive set my **ticketprice** to **DECIMAL(8,2) Not NULL** in my database. Before this, theres no **ticketprice** and it updates well in the database and it outputs to the recipt.php. But now, after i added this new column, it doesnt seem to go through the **'if'** loop and i dont know where i did wrong so im guessing im wrong in my **$result = ...** statement but im not sure why. Since it doesnt go through the **'if'** loop, it outputs the two echos (see code comment) and "failure" statement.

```
<?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
            if($_SESSION['logged']==true){
                $username = $_SESSION['login_user'];
                $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
                $ticketprice = $quantity*1.70;

                $host = "localhost";
                $dbusername = "root";
                $dbpassword = "";
                $dbname = "ktm_member";
                $dbtable = "member selection list";

                $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword) or die("cannot connect");
                mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname) or die("Cannot select db");

                $query="SELECT * FROM `member list` WHERE `Username` = '$_SESSION[login_user]'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                if($count==1){
                    //this two echos works fine
                    echo "ticket price:";
                    echo $ticketprice;
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO `member select ticket`(`username`, `journeyfrom`, `journeyto`, `date`, `time`, `quantity`, `ticketprice`) VALUES ('$username','$_POST[journeyfrom]','$_POST[journeyto]','$_POST[date]','$_POST[time]','$_POST[quantity]'), '$ticketprice')";

                    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                    //but it doesnt seem to go through this if loop
                    if($result){
                        echo "<b>Success</b>";
                        header('Location: http://localhost/mysql/receipt.php'); exit;

                    } else {
                        echo "<b>Failure<b>";
                    }
                } 
            }
        }   
    ?>
```

Comment: Hi, I think the ticketprice column is a Double not varchar so try removing single quotes and try again.

Comment: @UssaidIqbal you mean for the ticketprice with $ sign or without $ sign?

Comment: Cross-Site Scripting Attack through SQL injection is open for your code please try `prepare("")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the syntax error

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `member select ticket`(`username`, `journeyfrom`, `journeyto`, `date`, `time`, `quantity`, `ticketprice`) VALUES ('$username','$_POST[journeyfrom]','$_POST[journeyto]','$_POST[date]','$_POST[time]','$_POST[quantity]', '$ticketprice')";
```

you are wide open for SQLIjection, all I would have to do is change this:

```
 $_POST[quantity] = "10', 0) --";
```

And I just got your product (10 of them) for free because:

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `member select ticket`(..., `quantity`, `ticketprice`) VALUES (..., '10', 0) --'100.00')";
```

The `--` is an inline comment and comments out the rest of the query, so In effect I set the quantity to 10 and the price to 0 and commented the rest of your query out.

Let's break it down a bit more, This part of your query `'$_POST[quantity]', '$ticketprice')";` directly injects data from the `$_POST` array, something any client can change just by going in the debug mode of the browser `f12` and editing the form.

When I change that from `10` to `"10', 0) --"` this happens.

- `$_POST[quantity]` is replaced with `10`

  - or `(..., quantity,ticketprice)VALUES(...,'10,'$ticketprice')`
- the open quote is closed with `'`

  - or `(..., quantity,ticketprice)VALUES(...,'10','$ticketprice')`
- add in a comma for the next input value `,`

  - or `(..., quantity,ticketprice)VALUES(...,'10',,'$ticketprice')`
- add in my new price of `0`

  - or `(..., quantity,ticketprice)VALUES(...,'10',0,'$ticketprice')`
- add in the closing parentheses `)` to close the VALUES

  - or `(..., quantity,ticketprice)VALUES(...,'10',0),'$ticketprice')`
- comment the rest of the SQL statement out `--`

  - or `(..., quantity,ticketprice)VALUES(...,'10',0) --,'$ticketprice')`
  - or without the comment `(..., quantity,ticketprice)VALUES(...,'10',0)`

I would Highly suggest you read up on prepared statements!  To prevent these kind of attacks against your site.

In most cases you would never know how I was able to acquire these "tickets" whatever they are for free. Maybe there would be something in the server logs, but what would you do in that case. Would you even know I hacked this form, if this is mostly automated.  Maybe you would see it on a receipt but what would you say to me about it?

As a business it's not a chance that can be even remotely considered.  It's totally unacceptable, besides any legal repercussions such as being sued, it would probably destroy your reputation.  And if you spent any amount of money building a brand it would all be up in smoke.  Users would ask if it's that easy to hack your site, are my credit cards safe on a site like that....

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Will do. Thank you.

Comment: As a general rule, never concatenate data into a query. Even if you think its safe such as `$_SESSION[login_user]`, it may not be. If you assign the users login they gave you `$_SESSION['login_user'] = $_POST['login_user']` instead of  `$_SESSION['login_user'] = $row['login_user']`  from the DB, there is the possibility they can compromise the data. It may be slim in this example, but is it worth taking the chance? I would say, never is it worth risking you reputation as a site that your users can trust.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

> $sql = "INSERT INTO `member select ticket`(`username`, `journeyfrom`, `journeyto`, `date`, `time`, `quantity`, `ticketprice`) VALUES ('$username','$_POST[journeyfrom]','$_POST[journeyto]','$_POST[date]','$_POST[time]','$_POST[quantity]', $ticketprice)";

The problem  was there was an extra **)** remove it and you are good to go!

And one more thing of there is something wrong with your query and it's returning false, you can look for error in your else block by

**echo mysqli_error($conn);**

Comment: What is your table name?

Comment: Try echoing the query error and see if there something wrong with your query still make sure the table name is correct as well as the columns.

Comment: 'member select ticket' table.

Comment: I got this:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES ('donald','Tg. Malim','Tg. Malim','2018-09-05','09:05','1', '1.7')' at line 1

Comment: You did not removed single quotes